# Group of order $q^3p^3$, where $p,q$ are twin primes greater than $10$, is solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, p-groups, solvable-groups

> Let $q>p>10$ be twin primes, i.e., $q=p+2$. Show that every group of order $q^3p^3$ is solvable.

This should be proven without using Burnside's theorem. Looking at the Sylow $p$-subgroup and Sylow $q$-subgoup, their number is $k_p \in {1, q, q^2, q^3}$ and similarly for $k_q$. But I don't see how it helps, how do I countinue from here?

Comment: See this link https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Finite_solvable_group. Maybe helpful

Comment: But the restriction to $p>10$ makes it very easy. Remember that $k_p \equiv 1 \bmod p$.

Comment: There is an equivalent definition of finite solvable group which says it must have sylow complements for all primes dividing the order of the group. That's why I said maybe helpful. If not, then ignore it

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya This is an easy application of Sylow's theorem, so there is no need for anything more advanced.

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya What do you mean by Sylow complements for all primes?

Comment: @DerekHolt Can you give some more specific instructions? I don't see an immediate way that $k_p\equiv 1 \mod p$ helps, so I might be missing the important part.

Comment: I cannot see what you could be missing. You have already written down $q=p+2$ and $k_p=1,q,q^2$ or $q^3$. Just use that together with $k_p  \equiv 1 \bmod p$ and see what it gives you.

Comment: Have you noticed that $q\equiv 2\pmod{p}$? What is $q^2$ modulo $p$?

Comment: Yes, it is clear now, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you know that $p$-groups are solvable ($p$ prime). Now in your case let $P \in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$, then

$$n_p(G)=\#{\rm Syl}_p(G) \in \{1,p+2, (p+2)^2, (p+2)^3\}.$$

Since $n_p(G) \equiv 1$ mod $p$, it follows that $P$ is normal (the first option) or (all mod $p$) $2 \equiv 1$, $4 \equiv 1$ or $8 \equiv 1$. Hence $P \unlhd G$ or $p$ divides one of $\{1, 3, 7\}$. Since $p \gt 10$ is a prime, it must be at least $11$ and all the last possibilities are refuted. Hence $P$ is normal. But then $G/P$ is a $q$-group and hence solvable and $P$ is of course solvable. It follows that $G$ itself is solvable.

This is the proof Derek and Arturo had in mind!